# How to measure screen rendering time in Compose and XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 similar apps in Compose and XML. XML is using single activity and fragments for each screen. Compose using one activity and composable screens and navigation using Navigation Component for Compose.

I want to measure performance in this apps. I need to measure somehow first start time and time from opening to rendering first frame of each screen. I tried to find something and met some articles on Medium but their more about results and not about how to setup something for measurement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Macrobenchmark library. That will allow you to measure startup time and rendering performance.

Blog: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/measure-and-improve-performance-with-macrobenchmark-560abd0aa5bb

Docs: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/benchmarking/macrobenchmark-overview

Codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-macrobenchmark-inspect#0

Sample: https://github.com/android/performance-samples/tree/main/MacrobenchmarkSample

Comment: Thanks. But how can we measure fragments/screens (in compose) rendering speed?

Comment: That codelab will guide you through it. You use a FrameTimingMetric

Comment: i see you can use tags for composables as modifier. Is there any tags for fragments? Codelabs only telling about Compose version

Comment: The tests use UIAutomator. You just have to navigate to the screen you want to test, it doesn't matter if it's view or compose. Here are some view examples for UIAutomator. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator

Comment: Have you got any project samples of how to measure each screen? I never used test before

Comment: I can't really understand how can i measure each screen start with this. I have bottom nav bar in app. For example i want to navigate to second screen from bottom nav and measure how long this screen will take to open. How can i do that?

Comment: I added a sample link to the answer for you

Comment: Can you please tell how to navigate to item in `NavigationBar`? If i'm trying to set `testTag()` to items it doesn't navigate because result is null (Compose)

Comment: @BenTrengrove I think the examples mesaure startup time and frame delays, but not precisely screen transition times. For that we probably need to use `TraceSectionMetric` adding explicit declarations in our app code.